# Congruence on inverse semigroup

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse-semigroups

Could you, please, help me understand the reason why we are interested in trace of a congruence and the kernel's congruence when we're talking about the congruences on inverse semigroup. Also, I have read that congruences of an inverse semigroup are classified according to their traces? could you explain that?

Note that trace $(p)= \{ (e,f): e,f \in E(S)\}$, where $E(S)$ is the set of idempotents.

Comment: A congruence is determined by its have trace and kernel.  See Lawson 's book.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? I need to get the idea clearly